# Emma not recording line coverage even though it executed

Tags: emma

Am using emma for recording code coverage. Am particularly interested in the line coverage (or line %) We are planning to increase the line coverage for our source code thru' automation. We first execute the scenarios manually and then check using emma if there is an increase in line%. If there is, we go ahead and automate that feature. Am stuck with a particular IF-ELSE block where i see the desired result when i manually run the scenario. But emma is not recording the line as covered. Here's the sample code below

```
    if (a == null) 
             {
                 final class1 c1 = new class1();
                 if (c1.isSE()) 
                 {
                    c1.sendRedirect(req, res, "error.html");
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     c1.sendRedirect(req, res, "testpage.html");
                 }
                 return;
             }
```

First 3 lines are green in emma report. But, the following lines below are in red in the emma report (meaning they are not covered)

```
c1.sendRedirect(req, res, "error.html");
c1.sendRedirect(req, res, "testpage.html");
return;
```

But when i execute the scenario manually, am seeing the desired result (i.e. am redirected to testpage.html page) Why is emma not recording this line as covered?

Note: I have tried the following troubleshooting below (mentioned in http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html )

> 3.18. EMMA started reporting that it instrumented 0 classes even though I gave it some input...
>
> You might be getting tripped up by the incremental nature of EMMA instrumentation. When debugging an EMMA-enabled build, try either a
>   clean recompile and/or delete all instrumentation output directories
>   and all *.em/*.ec files by hand to reset EMMA to a clean state.

Comment: How are you generating the report? What build tool do you use?

Answer (score 1):

May be useful for the future people who refer to this...

When you instrument the Jars.you can see emma listing some of the classes with "Class Compiled without Debug Mode". If you see these messages when instrumenting then the Line % Coverage will not be generated. To overcome this you either need to compile those classes in debug mode or consider excluding if those classes are not required. Usually the classes with the above mentioned message will be third party classes.

If you don't see the Message "Class Compiled without Debug Mode" while instrumenting  - then you should see the Line coverage in your report.